# Why "Potential leak of memory pointed to by field" on Factory look-up-table

Tags: memory-leaks, c++17, static-analysis

I'm trying to implement a factory which creates new instances of types inherited by a common base class *Field*.

The factory is modeled as look-up-table to factory functions which return a unique_ptr. The key type of the look-up-table is a string_view.

Within the factory functions I call make_unique for the requested type.

clang-analyzer complains about a potential memory leak at the return of the unique_ptr.

The factory look-up-table with a single available factory entry.

```cpp
  using FieldFactory = std::function< std::unique_ptr< Field >( node const&, Clf const& ) >;

  static const std::unordered_map< std::string_view, FieldFactory > fieldFactoryLut = {
    {"static-text"sv, []( auto const& node, auto const& parent ) { return std::make_unique< StaticTextField >( node, parent ); }}
  };
```

Usage

```cpp
auto const& factoryFun = fieldFactoryLut.at("static-text"sv);
auto uPtr = factoryFun(node, clf);
```

By calling make_unique I expect no possible memory leak, but clang-analyzer claims:

```
warning: Potential leak of memory pointed to by field '_M_head_impl' [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks]
[build]     {"static-text"sv, []( auto const& node, auto const& parent ) { return std::make_unique< StaticTextField >( node, parent ); }}
```

Can anyone tell me what clang is seeing here?

Comment: Which clang version are you using?  I couldn't repro this with versions 7 or 8.  Can you supply a godbolt link?

Comment: I ran scan-build-7 which comes with clang 7.0.0.3